# Android cannot reach SignalR server over WiFi/LAN while OK via 3G

Tags: android, xamarin, signalr

Setup:

1. Windows machine running Self-hosting SignalR server.
2. Windows App with SignalR client.
3. Android App with SignalR client.
4. LAN with Ethernet/Wi-Fi. The (1) SignalR server is on this LAN. All firewalls are disabled.
5. 4G external network. (1) SignalR server can be reached via dedicated IP Address.

Both 2 and 3 and developed with Xamarin and use the same SignalR related code and libraries.

Test results:

- Connecting (2) Windows App to (1) SignalR server via (4) LAN: OK
- Connecting (2) Windows App to (1) SignalR server via (5) 4G: OK
- Connecting (3) AndroidApp to (1) SignalR server via (5) 4G: OK
- **Connecting (3) AndroidApp to (1) SignalR server via (4) LAN: Doesn't connect.**
- Ping from Android device to (1)SignalR server via (4) LAN or (5) 4G: OK

Anyone have an idea what causes this problem and knows how to solve it?

Regards,

Arthur

Comment: Have you tried another WiFi network?

Comment: Hi Tomasz.
Yes. Same issue.

Comment: Is this a real device or emulator, or maybe both?

Comment: Tried several real devices and VS Android emu

Comment: Used SignalR in other Android projects without issue

Comment: When using 3 to 1, what´s the server ip you are trying to reach?

Comment: Try running powershell `netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.X.X:XXXX/ user=everyone` (if your system language is english) at your server machine